# Why InnoDb dont support auto_increment in clustered primary key

Tags: mysql, database

why innodb, doesn't support this option, and what to do instead. if i have a invoice and want sorted invoice detail entry number, how to get it without clustered primary key autoincrement.

Answer (score 0):

Because it would require communication between nodes every time when you are inserting a new record, and that is expensive. You can use random values as IDs instead. E.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29 + http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid